# sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.food.find/databases/mydatabase", &handle, 2, NULL) failed in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i am trying to create the database from assets  but is give me error unable to open database
but after i run again is not give error is complete run
when first time is create is give me error i put my logcat here

```
07-04 18:28:00.860: E/Database(990): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.temp.find/databases/tempfind", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
07-04 18:28:00.870: W/System.err(990): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
07-04 18:28:00.880: W/System.err(990):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
07-04 18:28:00.880: W/System.err(990):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
07-04 18:28:00.880: W/System.err(990):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
07-04 18:28:00.880: W/System.err(990):  at com.food.find.RestaurantDatabase.checkDataBase(RestaurantDatabase.java:97)
07-04 18:28:00.890: W/System.err(990):  at com.food.find.RestaurantDatabase.createDataBase(RestaurantDatabase.java:60)
07-04 18:28:00.890: W/System.err(990):  at com.food.find.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:25)
07-04 18:28:00.890: W/System.err(990):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-04 18:28:00.890: W/System.err(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-04 18:28:00.890: W/System.err(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-04 18:28:00.890: W/System.err(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-04 18:28:00.900: W/System.err(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-04 18:28:00.910: W/System.err(990):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 18:28:01.030: E/running(990): database opened page size
```

> RestaurantDatabase.java

```
public class RestaurantDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_FOODADDRESS="address";
    private static final String KEY_FOODPHONE = "phonenumber";
    private static final String KEY_LATITUDE="latitude";
    private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE="longitude";



    private static final String TAG_LAT="lat";
    private static final String TAG_LONG="lng";
    private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "responseData";
    private static final String TAG_TITLENOFORMATING = "titleNoFormatting";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESSLINES="addressLines";
    private static final String TAG_PHONENUMBERS="phoneNumbers";
    private static final String TAG_NUMBER="number";    
    private static final String TAG_FOOD="food";
    private static String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.temp.find/databases/";   
    private static String DB_NAME ="tempfind";   
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    private final Context myContext;    

    String query = "";

    public RestaurantDatabase(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext=context;     
    };

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {

         boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

         if(dbExist)
         {

         }
         else
         {


         this.getReadableDatabase();

         try
         {

             copyDataBase();

         } 
         catch (IOException e)
         {

             throw new Error("Error copying database");

         }

         }


    }


    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(checkDB != null)
        {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {


        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public RestaurantDatabase(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) 
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.myContext=context;
    }


        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException
        {     
                //Open the database
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                Log.e("running", "database opened page size");

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() 
        {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close(); 
            super.close();

        }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {


    }

    public String addContact(String title,String address,String phone,String latitude,String longitude) 
    {

        String check = null;

        Log.e("Title","--->"+title);
        Log.e("Address","-->"+address);
        Log.e("Number","-->"+phone);
        Log.e("Latitude","-->"+latitude);
        Log.e("Longitude","-->"+longitude);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME,title); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_FOODADDRESS,address); // Contact Address
        values.put(KEY_FOODPHONE,phone); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE,latitude); // Contact Latitude
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE,longitude); // Contact Longitude

        Log.e("addcontact called","--->");

        // Inserting Row
        myDataBase.insert(TAG_FOOD, null,values);       

        String selectQuery = " SELECT  * FROM " + TAG_FOOD ;

        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        Log.e("CURSOR RECORD","--->"+cursor.getCount());
        Log.e("INSERT RECORD","--->"+values);


        return check;


    }



}
```

Comment: have you add permission Write external storage to androidmanifest?

Comment: no i will add it and check again after reply you

Comment: do you even understand this code? ... it supposed to print this message if there is no `/data/data/com.temp.find/databases/tempfind` file

Comment: after added write external storage permission  is give me same error

Comment: @Selvin this give me complete path like you define /data/data/com.temp.find/databases/tempfind

Comment: i repeat: you don't understand the code ... it is working as it should ... buy a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and explain to it what will happend in `checkDataBase` if there is no `/data/data/com.temp.find/databases/tempfind` file !!!!

Comment: i got my problem for checkDataBase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your chekDatabase with this code this work completely

private boolean checkDataBase()
{

File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
  return dbFile.exists();

}

Answer (score 5):

This code is dreadful. I'd start by deleting the entire thing and beginning again.

First, if you are going to package a database with your app, do not write your own code for that. There is [an existing library, `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), that is tested, debugged, and supported. More importantly, it is written by somebody (Jeff Gilfelt) with a *lot* of Android development experience.

Second, if you are using a `SQLiteOpenHelper` (or a subclass like `SQLiteAssetHelper`), and you are *also* writing `openDatabase()` anywhere for that database, **YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG**. The complete and entire *point* behind `SQLiteOpenHelper` is to have *it* open the database for you, so it can create or upgrade that database if needed.

Third, if you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` (or a subclass like `SQLiteAssetHelper`), and you have *empty* an  empty `onCreate()` method, **YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG**. There needs to be code here to actually create the database, whether that is code that you inherit (e.g., from `SQLiteAssetHelper`) or code you write.

Fourth, if you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` (or a subclass like `SQLiteAssetHelper`), and you are calling `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` and *are ignoring the return value*, **YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG**. You call those methods to open the database, giving you your `SQLiteDatabase` for use.

There is plenty more wrong with this code, but this should be enough to get you moved over closer to a sensible implementation.